# Invoke a child MVC action from a controller given an arbitrary URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, routes

I have a controller method that needs to invoke (and get the HTML result from ) some other arbitrary "child" controller action.  The route for the "child" action is encoded in a URL.  What I want to do is parse the URL intro a route, get a controller that can execute the child action, simulate a request to the child action (obviously with some reasonable context), and then get the resulting HTML back.

I have tried a range of things (including an hour of trolling through SO posts on route parsing, creating controllers, etc.) but I'm stumped.

For example, ...

```
class SomeController
{
    public ActionResult Outer()
    {
        string exampleInnerPath = "/Other/Child/20";

        string output = EvaluateChildPath(exampleInnerPath);
        return Content(output, "text/xml");
    }
}

class OtherController
{
    public PartialViewResult Child(int arg)
    {
        return PartialView(arg);
    }
}
```

How would you write **EvaluateChildPath()**?

Any direction would be appreciated!